# Loading Angular from another file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some JS code like this:

```
              switch(sc.article.type) {
                case articleTypes.text:
                  template = "<div class='form-group'><div class='input-group' ng-show='article.suffix'><input class='form-control' type='text' ng-model='article.response'/><div class='input-group-addon'>{{ article.suffix }}</div></div><input class='form-control' type='text' ng-model='article.response' ng-show='!article.suffix'/></div><p class='help-block'>{{article.help}}</p>";
                  break;
                 case articleTypes.number:
                   ... etc
```

I think this could be structured more nicely. For example, for each `sc.article.type` I could put that HTML code for `template` in its own HTML file rather than trying to define it in-line.

But how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`$templateCache` service of angularjs will be helpful to you.

First put all your possible templates in `$templateCache`

```
angular.module('app', []).run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('text', "<div class='form-group'><div class='input-group' ng-show='article.suffix'><input class='form-control' type='text' ng-model='article.response'/><div class='input-group-addon'>{{ article.suffix }}</div></div><input class='form-control' type='text' ng-model='article.response' ng-show='!article.suffix'/></div><p class='help-block'>{{article.help}}</p>");
  $templateCache.put('number', 'number relaed template');
});
```

After configuring all templates. Now $templateCache will take care all this string.

Now with the same service you can retrieve the template in javascript also.

you can get template by template-id.

```
$templateCache.get('text');  to retrieve text template associated with 'text' switch case.


$templateCache.get('number'); to retrieve number related template. likewise....
```

You can write separate html files too.

See this example [Demo plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/J6Y2dc?p=preview) for both the ways.

1. Separate html files
2. Put templates in $templateCache.

Answer (score 0):

Generally wherever you can use `template: '<htmlString>'` in angular such as directives or routing config you can use `templateUrl: 'path/to/file`.

Note that `templateUrl` can also reat template `<script>` tags included in main page or read from `$templatCache` also using the same url

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @charlietfi answer: You can use `ng-switch` tag since you already using switch on string variable. So you'll define multiple directives, each with it's own template html file.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in a directive. It could be very, very simple:

```
app.directive("myArticle", function(){
  return { templateUrl : "template.html" }
});
```

It makes the html very clean:

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles">
  <div my-article></div>
</div>
```

The template file would still be a mess (especially if you add switches and ifs) but at least now it's hidden out of sight!

```
<!-- template.html -->
<div class='form-group' ng-if="article.type=='text'">
  <h4>This is a text</h4>
  <div class='input-group' ng-show='article.suffix'>
    <input class='form-control' type='text' ng-model='article.response' />
    <div class='input-group-addon'>
      {{ article.suffix }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <input class='form-control' type='text' ng-model='article.response' ng-show='!article.suffix' />
</div>
```

Working example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nHBSMHpj0tA7FAb0sft7?p=preview

Also if the templates doesn't differ much, the *really easy* solution would be to just toggle class (`ng-class="{'text':(article.type==articleTypes.text)}`) and simply hide unused fields using css.

And one more note: There are ways to make the templateUrl dynamic, for example depending on article.type. You can even pass it a function(element, attributes) , but the attributes are not linked at this point which makes it a hassle and adds extra complexity. So I would advice you to stay away from it if you can!